# Node Multer unexpected field

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm working on uploading a file to my app using the multer npm module.

The multer function I have defined is to allow a single file uploaded to the file system.  Everything works during run time; the issue is after I upload the file I get an error below.  Any advice appreciated on where to look.

## Error:

```
Unexpected field

Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (c:\Users\Dev\WebstormProjects\Crunch\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (c:\Users\Dev\WebstormProjects\Crunch\node_modules\multer\index.js:39:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Dev\WebstormProjects\Crunch\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:97:7)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:118:17)
    at Busboy.emit (c:\Users\Dev\WebstormProjects\Crunch\node_modules\multer\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:31:35)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Dev\WebstormProjects\Crunch\node_modules\multer\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:205:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Dev\WebstormProjects\Crunch\node_modules\multer\node_modules\busboy\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at HeaderParser._finish (c:\Users\Dev\WebstormProjects\Crunch\node_modules\multer\node_modules\busboy\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:70:8)
```

## app.js

```
var multer = require('multer');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

//. . . 

var upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/'});
var type = upload.single('file');

app.post('/upload', type, function (req,res) {
  var tmp_path = req.files.recfile.path;
  var target_path = 'uploads/' + req.files.recfile.name;
fs.readFile(tmp_path, function(err, data)
{
  fs.writeFile(target_path, data, function (err)
  {
    res.render('complete');
  })
});
```

## Index.hbs

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name='recfile' placeholder="Select file"/>
    <br/>
    <button>Upload</button>
</form>

#Package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "easy-zip": "0.0.4",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "less-middleware": "1.0.x",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "multer": "~1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 203, accepted):

> We have to make sure the type= file with name attribute should be same
>   as the parameter name passed in `upload.single('attr')`

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/'});
var fs = require('fs');

/** Permissible loading a single file, 
    the value of the attribute "name" in the form of "recfile". **/
var type = upload.single('recfile');

app.post('/upload', type, function (req,res) {

  /** When using the "single"
      data come in "req.file" regardless of the attribute "name". **/
  var tmp_path = req.file.path;

  /** The original name of the uploaded file
      stored in the variable "originalname". **/
  var target_path = 'uploads/' + req.file.originalname;

  /** A better way to copy the uploaded file. **/
  var src = fs.createReadStream(tmp_path);
  var dest = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
  src.pipe(dest);
  src.on('end', function() { res.render('complete'); });
  src.on('error', function(err) { res.render('error'); });

});
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this works and what's different? —_____—

Comment: Works perfectly like charm.We have to make sure the type= file with name attribute should be same as the parameter name passed in upload.single('attr')

Comment: Mine case it's not working. I am facing same issue. But in my windows machine code is working. I am having issues with my MAC.? Can anyone help with me this?

Comment: The name attribute of the type="file" in html should match the upload.single('name') in server code.

Comment: How to set the client request for a multiple files upload? The 'files' field is empty.

Comment: Note: @stdob seems like it want tmp file & dest file in same directory. Can't do an edit for this but take care: path are differents in the code (`upload/` 
and `uploads/`)

Comment: Mine works in osx but it leaves behind the temporary file which doesn't have an extension name and appears in some kinda of temporary file name "abd71003bbe62925b961681ce134d08c" in the same directory as final file

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked perfectly for me. I am left with only one issue which is currently my directory structure is like this:

Inside App folder there are two more directories one for frontend and another one for backend.

so currently the image is being saved inside the backend folder but I want to save it to the frontend folder so that I can reference it in my img tag.

Can you share the way how it can be done.

Comment: @stdob In my case when uploading multiple files `upload.array('photos', 10)` , I noticed **something strange**, First, ensured that `photos` was name that was being sent. but still received this error. Next I went inside `node_modules/multer/index.js` and just tried to **`console.log('file', file)`** inside the. **`function wrappedFileFilter (req, file, cb) {  console.log("file wrappedFileFilter Multer: ", file);.......}`**  To my surprise, just adding the `console.log` statement made the upload possible. How can this be, can someone explain this how? Thanks

Comment: @HaRdikKaji, did you find the answer for MAC ? I'm getting the same issue. Hope you remember the solution :)

Comment: is there any why we can pass error message to the client to tell that the field name you are providing is not same as you specified in upload.single('field name') ?

Comment: @SergeyNN Not really :D

Answer (score 346):

The `<NAME>` you use in multer's `upload.single(<NAME>)` function must be the same as the one you use in `<input type="file" name="<NAME>" ...>`.

So you need to change

`var type = upload.single('file')`

to

`var type = upload.single('recfile')`

in you app.js

Comment: It would help if they put this in the readme instead of filling it with 'avatar'.

Comment: But we still need to avoid the exception in case of misuse..
how to catch this exception?

Comment: Just for reference, if you're using curl, and the command looks like this:curl -v -F upload=@/myfile.txt http://localhost:3000/upload                   Then the value for upload.single is "upload"

Comment: You are right bro

Comment: @Vincent is there any why we can pass error message to the client to tell that the field name you are providing is not same as you specified in upload.single('field name') ?

Answer (score 53):

A follow up to vincent's answer.

Not a direct answer to the question since the question is using a form.

For me, it wasn't the name of the input tag that was used, but the name when appending the file to the formData.

front end file

```
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('<NAME>',this.new_attachments)
```

web service file:

```
   app.post('/upload', upload.single('<NAME>'),...
```

Comment: This saved my day. Thank you. 
If you use FormData.append() the name attribut from the <input> tag will be overwritten and makes the other solutions not working.

Comment: This answer is so important and incredibly helpful. Making sure that the `formData` key name is the same as the `upload` key argument is crucial. It works for me now.

Comment: This helped a lot.

Comment: Saved a lot of debugging time. God bless you.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me a lot, saved my day

Comment: For anyone using React or Next.js with an HttpClient like axios or fetch, this is the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 7):

This for the Api you could use

```
 const express        = require('express');
 const bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
 const app = express();
 var multer = require('multer');
 const port = 8000;
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 app.listen(port, ()=>{
 console.log('We are live on' + port);
 });

 var upload = multer({dest:'./upload/'});

 app.post('/post', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.file);
 res.send("file saved on server");
 });
```

This also works fine used on Postman
but the file doesn't comes with .jpg extension 
any Advice?
As commented below

This is the default feature of multer if uploads file with no extension, however, provides you the the file object, using which you can update the extension of the file.

```
var filename = req.file.filename; 
var mimetype = req.file.mimetype; 
mimetype = mimetype.split("/"); 
var filetype = mimetype[1]; 
var old_file = configUploading.settings.rootPathTmp+filename; 
var new_file = configUploading.settings.rootPathTmp+filename+'.'+filetype; 
rname(old_file,new_file);
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the name attribute of the input, use the key you are using to pass the file.

Example: My `FormData` Object:

Client Side:

```
formData.append('file', fileBlob);
```

Server Side:

```
multer.single('file');
```

Answer (score 5):

since 2 images are getting uploaded! one with file extension and other  file without extension.
to delete tmp_path (file without extension)

after 
`src.pipe(dest);`

add below code

`fs.unlink(tmp_path); //deleting the tmp_path`

Answer (score 4):

Different file name which posted as "**recfile**" at `<input type="file" name='recfile' placeholder="Select file"/>` and received as "**file**" at  `upload.single('file')`

**Solution** :  make sure both sent and received file are similar `upload.single('recfile')`

Answer (score 4):

## **2022-2023 Answer**

When using FormData and working with arrays, the multer variable name must also include the '**[]**', this did not use to be the case.

Old code:

```
const multerConfig = upload.fields([
    {name: 'photos', maxCount: 20}
])
```

**2022+** code:

```
const multerConfig = upload.fields([
    {name: 'photos[]', maxCount: 20}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was using `upload.array()`, and applying this same change resolved my issue.

Comment: I am not understanding, I have removed the '[]' part. Then worked for me. putting the '[]' make no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the error message doesn't provide clear information about what the real problem is.  For that, some debugging is required.

From the stack trace, here's the origin of the error in the `multer` package:

```
function wrappedFileFilter (req, file, cb) {
  if ((filesLeft[file.fieldname] || 0) <= 0) {
    return cb(makeError('LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE', file.fieldname))
  }

  filesLeft[file.fieldname] -= 1
  fileFilter(req, file, cb)
}
```

And the strange (possibly mistaken) translation applied here is the source of the message itself...

```
'LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE': 'Unexpected field'
```

`filesLeft` is an object that contains the name of the field your server is expecting, and `file.fieldname` contains the name of the field provided by the client.  The error is thrown when there is a mismatch between the field name provided by the client and the field name expected by the server.

The solution is to change the name *on either the client or the server* so that the two agree.

For example, when using `fetch` on the client...

```
var theinput = document.getElementById('myfileinput')
var data = new FormData()
data.append('myfile',theinput.files[0])
fetch( "/upload", { method:"POST", body:data } )
```

And the server would have a route such as the following...

```
app.post('/upload', multer(multerConfig).single('myfile'),function(req, res){
  res.sendStatus(200)
}
```

Notice that it is `myfile` which is the common name (in this example).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your comment gave me a hint about my error. In my case, I had 2 forms in differents views and differents router files. The first router used the name field with view one and its file name was "imgLoading". The second view had another name the file input. For some reason multer not allows  you set differentes name in different views, so I dicided used same name for the file input in both views.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this issues looking for the name that I passed on my request

I was sending on body:

```
{thumbbail: <myimg>}
```

and I was expect to:

```
upload.single('thumbnail')
```

so, I fix the name that a send on request

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario this was happening because I renamed a parameter in `swagger.yaml` but did not reload the docs page.
Hence I was trying the API with an unexpected input parameter.
Long story short, <kbd>F5</kbd> is my friend.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are not giving the same name as you mentioned in the 
`upload.single('file')` .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had 2 forms in differents views and differents router files. The first router used the name field with view one and its file name was "inputGroupFile02". The second view had another name for file input. For some reason Multer not allows  you set differents name in different views, so I dicided to use same name for the file input in both views.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading single and multiple files at the same time it would be recommended **not to use** middleware as :

```
app.use(
  multer(
    { 
      storage: fileStorage, 
      limits:
        { 
          fileSize:'2mb' 
        }, 
      fileFilter: fileFilter 
    }
  ).fields(
    [
      { 
        name: 'resume', 
        maxCount: 1 
      }, 
      { 
        name: 'image', 
        maxCount: 1 
      }
    ]
  )
);
```

Would be suitable for you just to create a simple storage with if function

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination:(req,file,cb)=>{
    if (file.fieldname === 'image'){
      cb(null, './public/images/productcover')
    }
    else if(file.fieldname === 'gallery'){
      cb(null, './public/images/productgallery')
    }
  },
  filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})
```

In my case image is a single file and gallery is a multiple image upload input.

And in the post method to use `upload.fields()` method

```
app.post('/products', upload.fields([{
    name: "image"
  }, {
    name: "gallery"
  }]) ,function (req,res){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`App.js`:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

//Add this on the top of application -> app.use(forms.array("name", maxFiles));

var upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/'});

// Remove this part of code -> var type = upload.single('file');

app.post('/upload', function (req,res) { // on this function we do not need type as well
  var tmp_path = renter code hereeq.files.recfile.path;
  var target_path = 'uploads/' + req.files.recfile.name;
fs.readFile(tmp_path, function(err, data)
{
  fs.writeFile(target_path, data, function (err)
  {
    res.render('complete');
  })
});
```