# Getting error while making API call for multer to store files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I created a node API using multer to store files and i'm getting error while calling it, please help. Bellow is the code and error -

Code -

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/upload',
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

// initialize upload
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {fieldSize: 100000}
}).single('myImage');

app.post('/upload', (req, res)=> {  
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if(err){
            res.json({
                msg: req.body,
            });
        }else {
            res.json({
                msg: 'File uploaded',
                file: `upload/${req.file.filename}`
            });
        }
    })
})
```

The error i'm getting while making API call is "name": "MulterError", "message": "Unexpected field", "code": "LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE", "storageErrors": []

Comment: Try not using `limits: {fieldSize: 100000}` attribute.

Comment: Still no luck, getting error -
{
    "msg": {
        "name": "MulterError",
        "message": "Unexpected field",
        "code": "LIMIT_UNEXPECTED_FILE",
        "storageErrors": []
    }
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530200/node-multer-unexpected-field

Answer (score 1):

Passing the filename works for me -

```js
uploadFile = (e) =>{
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append('myImage', file);
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
  }).then(res => this.setState({file: res.data.file}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your Frontend code have you made sure the input name is  myImage

If you are using HTML try using this code

```
   <input type=“file” name=“myImage” />
```

Suppose you are using the front end framework react

This piece of code should be in the submit/ uploadFile  function

```
  const uploadFile = (e) =>{
       e.preventDefault();
      let file = e.target.files[0];
      let data = new FormData();
      data.append('myImage', file);
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', data, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
      }).then(res => this.setState({file: res.data.file}));
    }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Using React in front end, and using same name 
<input type="file" onChange={(e)=> {this.uploadFile(e)}} name="myImage" />

Comment: Yes it works by passing name into KEY in API call. It was my bad, maybe i made it wrong.

Comment: Check my edited answer should help with using react

Comment: Try the react code and share any other issues you may be having

Comment: 1st comment(was deleted)  For debugging purpose you should try making a request on postman

Comment: Working code -

uploadFile = (e) =>{
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append('fileName', file);
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
  }).then(res => this.setState({file: res.data.file}));
}

Answer (score 0):

```
limits: {fileSize: 100000}
```

I didn't check it but I believe it has to be fileSize not fieldSize, probably