I am getting this error while making patch request in Postman
This is what I am sending from PostmanI tried to update the coverImage and file but I am getting this error
MulterError: Unexpected field    at wrappedFileFilter (D:\MERN\RestAPIs\elearn\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)    at Multipart.<anonymous> (D:\MERN\RestAPIs\elearn\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:107:7)    at Multipart.emit (node:events:520:28)    at Multipart.emit (node:domain:488:12)    at HeaderParser.cb (D:\MERN\RestAPIs\elearn\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:358:14)    at HeaderParser.push (D:\MERN\RestAPIs\elearn\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:162:20)    at SBMH.ssCb [as _cb] (D:\MERN\RestAPIs\elearn\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:394:37)    at feed (D:\MERN\RestAPIs\elearn\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:219:14)    at SBMH.push (D:\MERN\RestAPIs\elearn\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:104:16)    at Multipart._write (D:\MERN\RestAPIs\elearn\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:567:19)
bookRouter.js
bookRouter.patch("/update/:bookId", authenticate, upload.fields([             // as a middleware
    {name: "coverImage", maxCount: 1},
    {name: "file", maxCount: 1},

])  ,updateBook);

bookController.js
const updateBook = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    const {title, genre} = req.body;
    const bookId = req.params.bookId;

    const book = await bookModel.findOne({_id: bookId});

    if(!book) {

        return next(createHttpError(404, "Book not found"));

    }

    //check access 
    const _req = req as AuthRequest;
    if(book.author.toString() != _req.userId){

        return next(createHttpError(403, "You cannot update others book"))
    }

    //check if imagr filed is exist
    const files = req.files as { [fieldname: string]: Express.Multer.File[]};
    let completeCoverImage = "";
    
        const fileName = files.coverImage[0].filename;
        const coverMimeType = files.coverImage[0].mimetype.split("/").at(-1);
        
       
        // send files to cloudinary

 
        const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public/data/uploads', fileName);


        completeCoverImage = fileName;

        try {
            const uploadResult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(filePath, {
                filename_override: completeCoverImage,
                folder: "book-cover",
                format: coverMimeType,
            });
            console.log('uploadResult', uploadResult);
    
            completeCoverImage = uploadResult.secure_url;
    
            // Delete the local file after uploading to Cloudinary
            if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
                await fs.promises.unlink(filePath);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error while uploading or processing the image:', err);
            return next(createHttpError(500, "Error processing the cover image"));
        }
     /*else {
        console.error('Cover image file not found');
        return next(createHttpError(400, "Cover image file is required"));*/
    

    let completeFileName = "";
    if(files.file) {
        const bookFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../public/data/uploads" + files.file[0].filename);

        const bookFileName = files.file[0].filename;
        completeFileName = bookFileName;

        const uploadResultPdf = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(bookFilePath, {
            resource_type: "raw",
            filename_override: completeFileName,
            folder: "book-pdfs",
            format: "pdf",
        });

        console.log('uploadResultPdf',uploadResultPdf);

        try{
            completeFileName = uploadResultPdf.secure_url;
            await fs.promises.unlink(bookFilePath); 
        } catch(err){
            console.log('PDF', err);
        }  

    }
    
    const updatedBook = await bookModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            _id: bookId,
        },
        {
            title: title,
            genre: genre,
            coverImage: completeCoverImage ? completeCoverImage : book.coverImage,
            file: completeFileName ? completeFileName : book.file,
        },
        {new: true}
    );
    //console.log('completeCoverImage:', completeCoverImage);
    //console.log('completeFileName:', completeFileName);


    res.json(updatedBook);
    

authenticate.js
const authenticate = (req: Request, res:Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    const token = req.header('Authorization')
    if(!token){
        return next(createHttpError(401, "Authorization token is required"));
    }

    try{

        const parsedToken = token.split(' ')[1];

        const decoded = verify(parsedToken, config.jwtSecret as string);

        console.log(decoded);

        const _req = req as AuthRequest;

        _req.userId = decoded.sub as string;

        next();
    }catch(err){
        return next(createHttpError(401, "Token expired"));
    }    

};

I am trying to update the coverImage and file but getting the error.

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530200/node-multer-unexpected-field
